# Using an itemListener with JCheckBox to show/hide JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, jcheckbox, itemlistener

I'm trying to create an application that allows a user to choose insurance options in JCheckBoxes. For each option that is selected, the name and price are supposed to appear in a text field. My problem is that even when I select it, it doesn't display the Name & Price. At the moment I'm just trying to make the HMO checkbox work.

```
package p3s4;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class JInsurance extends JFrame implements ItemListener
{       
        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
        final double HMO_PRICE = 200;
        final double PPO_PRICE = 600;
        final double DENTAL_PRICE = 75;
        final double VISION_PRICE = 20;
        JLabel heading = new JLabel("Choose insurance options: ");
        JCheckBox hmo = new JCheckBox("HMO");
        JCheckBox ppo = new JCheckBox("PPO");
        ButtonGroup providersGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        JCheckBox dental = new JCheckBox("Dental");
        JCheckBox vision = new JCheckBox("Vision");
        JTextField hmoSelection = new JTextField(hmo + " " + HMO_PRICE);
public JInsurance()
{
    super("Insurance Options");

    setLayout(flow);
    add(heading);
    providersGroup.add(hmo);
    providersGroup.add(ppo);
    add(hmo);
    add(ppo);
    add(dental);
    add(hmoSelection);
    hmoSelection.setVisible(false);
    add(vision);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    hmo.addItemListener(this);
}
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
{
    if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
    {
            hmoSelection.setVisible(true);
    }    
    else
        hmoSelection.setVisible(false);
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JInsurance first = new JInsurance();
    final int WIDTH = 400;
    final int HEIGHT = 300;
    first.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    first.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Is the method itemStateChange() being invoked, if you set a breakpoint inside it?

Comment: No, I do not believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in your if block and it will work as expected

```
hmoSelection.getParent().revalidate();
```

The API docs for [revalidate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate()):

> Revalidates the component hierarchy up to the nearest validate root.
>
> This method first invalidates the component hierarchy starting from this component up to the nearest validate root. Afterwards, the component hierarchy is validated starting from the nearest validate root.
>
> This is a convenience method supposed to help application developers avoid looking for validate roots manually. Basically, it's equivalent to first calling the invalidate() method on this component, and then calling the validate() method on the nearest validate root.

Comment: Thank you! The JTextField works now, the issue now is that it still doesn't display the name and price. It works if I write it out as a string, but if I try to concatenate the string with the hmo variable or the HMO_PRICE constant it won't work. I'm not sure if doing that is even possible though.

Comment: Try replacing `JTextField hmoSelection = new JTextField(hmo + " " + HMO_PRICE);` to `JTextField hmoSelection = new JTextField(hmo.getName() + " " + HMO_PRICE)`

Comment: You've been so incredibly helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @Eleyna Also try adding `Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    first.setLocation(dim.width/2-first.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-first.getSize().height/2);` at the end of your main(). This will help your frame to open in the centre of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you add or remove something from an already visible UI, you have to call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the parent container.

```
hmoSelection.setVisible(true);
hmoSelection.getParent().revalidate();
//above revalidate method was introduced to Container in 1.7, call validate for earlier versions
hmoSelection.repaint();
```

A similar problem (and answers) can be found at [After calling setVisible(false) my JFrame contents are gone when calling set Visible(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085804/after-calling-setvisiblefalse-my-jframe-contents-are-gone-when-calling-set-vis)

Comment: FYI there is no method called getParentContainer() in Component class. However, I appreciate ur explanation!! 
Also, i dont feel calling the repaint() and there by calling the update(graphics).Simple revalidate() does the need

Comment: @Lalit Rao, thanks. Quoting [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/problems.html) themselves: `You need to invoke revalidate and repaint after adding a component before it will show up in your container.`

Comment: I totally agree with you mate, but in Eleyna's case the component ( JTextField hmoSelection) was already initialized in the constructor. So mere calling revalidate() would do the work. I debugged this code myself at my end. It would have been a different scenario for Eleyna would've tried adding textfield dynamically ..